# Weird behaviour in JavaFX list view elements

Tags: java, javafx

I have 2 list views, on the right one I have three "cards" (name and a value), each with a button which when clicked adds that card to the centerlist. I also can click on the same button of that card on the centerlist to remove that. My problem is if I add two or more card to the centerList and I proceed to remove them, the interface goes weird not deleting them or only one or two.

```java
public class DeckManagement implements Initializable {
    private final SceneHandler sceneHandler = SceneHandler.getInstance();
@FXML
    private ListView<Card> rightList;

    @FXML
    private ListView<Card> centerList;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        rightList.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Card>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Card card, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(card, empty);
                if (empty || card == null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    VBox container = new VBox();
                    Button cardButton = new Button("Add");
                    cardButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                        if (!card.isMoved()) {
                            centerList.getItems().add(card);
                            //rightList.getItems().remove(card);
                            card.setMoved(true);
                        }
                    });
                    container.getChildren().addAll(new javafx.scene.control.Label(card.toString()), cardButton);
                    setGraphic(container);
                }
            }
        });
        rightList.getItems().addAll(
            new Card("Card 1", 10),
            new Card("Card 2", 5),
            new Card("Card 3", 8)
        );
        centerList.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Card>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Card card, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(card, empty);
                if (empty || card == null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    VBox container = new VBox();
                    Button cardButton = new Button("Remove");
                    cardButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                        card.setMoved(false);
                        centerList.getItems().remove(card);
                    });
                    container.getChildren().addAll(new javafx.scene.control.Label(card.toString()), cardButton);
                    setGraphic(container);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. note: you __must not__ repeatedly create nodes in updateItem - instead create them once (either in initialization of the cell or lazyly in updateItem), and configure them according to the data in subsequent calls

Comment: also updateItem has to be symmetric in the empty/null vs !empty/null if/else block: in the former you have to remove/reset whatever you added/configured in the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list cell becomes non-empty, it's `updateItem(...)` method will be called with a non-null `Card` and a value of `false` for `empty`. In this case you set the graphic for that cell to the `VBox`.

If, subsequently, the `Card` instance displayed in that cell is removed from the `ListView` and the cell becomes empty, then `updateItem(null, true)` will be called. However your `updateItem(...)` implementation in this case does not remove the graphic, so the graphic remains displayed.

Here is an implementation that should work. I refactored this to avoid repeatedly creating new controls (which is extremely inefficient) and also to remove unnecessary repetitive code.

```
public class DeckManagement implements Initializable {
    private final SceneHandler sceneHandler = SceneHandler.getInstance();
    @FXML
    private ListView<Card> rightList;

    @FXML
    private ListView<Card> centerList;

    private static class DeckCell extends ListCell<Card> {
 
        private final VBox container;
        private final Button cardButton ;
        private final Label label;

        DeckCell(String buttonText) {
            label = new Label();
            cardButton = new Button(buttonText);
            container = new VBox(label, cardButton);

            cardButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                Card card = getItem();
                if (card.isMoved()) {
                    centerList.getItems().remove(card);
                } else {
                    centerList.getItems().add(card);
                    // rightList.getItems().remove(card);
                }
                card.setMoved(! card.isMoved());
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Card card, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(card, empty);
            if (empty || card == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                label.setText(card.toString());
                setGraphic(container);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        rightList.setCellFactory(param -> new DeckCell("Add")); 
        rightList.getItems().addAll(
            new Card("Card 1", 10),
            new Card("Card 2", 5),
            new Card("Card 3", 8)
        );
        centerList.setCellFactory(param -> new DeckCell("Remove"));
    }
}
```

Note that if you implement your `Card` class using a JavaFX property to represent "moved", your action handler can just update the property and the lists can take care of themselves:

```
public class Card {

    private final BooleanProperty moved = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public BooleanProperty movedProperty() {
        return moved ;
    }

    public final boolean isMoved() {
        return movedProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setMoved(boolean moved) {
        movedProperty().set(moved);
    }

    private final String name ;
    private final int value ;

    public Card(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name ;
        this.value = value ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

then

```
public class DeckManagement implements Initializable {
    private final SceneHandler sceneHandler = SceneHandler.getInstance();
    @FXML
    private ListView<Card> rightList;

    @FXML
    private ListView<Card> centerList;

    private static class DeckCell extends ListCell<Card> {
 
        private final VBox container;
        private final Button cardButton ;
        private final Label label;

        private final boolean movedValue;

        DeckCell(String buttonText, boolean movedValue) {
            this.movedValue = movedValue;

            label = new Label();
            cardButton = new Button(buttonText);
            container = new VBox(label, cardButton);

            cardButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                Card card = getItem();
                card.setMoved(movedValue);
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Card card, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(card, empty);
            if (empty || card == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                label.setText(card.toString());
                setGraphic(container);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ObservableList<Card> allCards = FXCollections.observableArrayList(card -> new Observable[] { card.movedProperty() });
        rightList.setItems(allCards);
        rightList.setCellFactory(param -> new DeckCell("Add", true)); 

        allCards.addAll(
            new Card("Card 1", 10),
            new Card("Card 2", 5),
            new Card("Card 3", 8)
        );

        // List that fires updates if any moved properties change:
        centerList.setItems(new FilteredList<>(allCards, card::isMoved));
        centerList.setCellFactory(param -> new DeckCell("Remove", false));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your advises, i followed James_D's code refactoring DeckCell Class as an abstract one, so that i could implement 2 more having as the only difference the button.setOnAction.
Because on one list the elements could add themselves to the other, and on the other list to only delete themselves.

Comment: @Shodan4004 See the second version, which implements that same functionality in a slightly different way.